Change API destination SOAP request without SFTP
Im doing an extraction via API, but it seems that necessary have to pass through an sftp, I wanted to change the destination to save it in a bucket (gcp) or other destination.
But the documentation doesnt offer the option to save it into other destination, there other way without passing by sftp? (since by default it saves the response zip file in Export/)
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_as_api_data_extract_options.htm&type=5
Glad if there is any other option or alternative! thanks!

Have you tried custom FTP location https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_overview_set_up_external_ftp_location.htm&type=5
